# I want to show multiple array

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have a code:

```
$surat_id = 'SB-1';
$opd = array(13, 14);
$opd_id = implode(',', $opd);
$ex = explode(',', $opd_id);

foreach ($ex as $key => $h) {
 $data = array(
  'surat_id' => $surat_id, 
  'opd_id' => $h,
 );
}
print_r($data);
```

The result is: `Array ( [surat_id] => SB-1 [opd_id] => 14 )`

But I want result as:

```
Array ( [surat_id] => SB-1 [opd_id] => 13 )

Array ( [surat_id] => SB-1 [opd_id] => 14 )
```

How should I get this result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$surat_id = 'SB-1';
$opd = array(13, 14);
$data = array();
foreach ($opd as $key => $h) {
   $data1 = array(
      'surat_id' => $surat_id, 
      'opd_id' => $h,
   );
   array_push($data,$data1);
}
echo'<pre>';print_r($data);die;
```

Comment: what variable i should echo for the result?

Comment: your welcome, kindly accept the answer so other users can find this answer easly